# query sql server - error when grouping fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this query

```
SELECT 
     B.IdDepartment,
     B.IdParent,
     CASE 
        WHEN B.IdParent = 3 THEN 'SANTO DOMINGO'
        WHEN B.IdParent = 4 THEN 'BAVARO'
        ELSE 'INACTIVOS' END AS Localidad, 
     A.IdUser As Codigo, 
     A.Name As Nombre, 
     B.Description As Departamento,
     CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime,102) As Fecha,
     CASE
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 1 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 6 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 2 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 0 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 3 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 1 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 4 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 2 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 5 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 3 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 6 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 4 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN  (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 7
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 5 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
            END AS [Hora Entrada],
     CASE
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 1 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 6 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 2 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 0 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 3 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 1 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 4 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 2 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 5 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 3 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 6 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 4 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 7
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 5 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
            END AS [Hora Salida],
     CASE
        WHEN(SELECT H.CuttingHour FROM Shift H INNER JOIN UserShift G ON H.ShiftId = G.ShiftId WHERE G.IdUser = A.IdUser) <> 0
            THEN (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(TIME,RecordTime)) FROM Record M WHERE M.RecordTime BETWEEN (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift X INNER JOIN UserShift Z ON X.ShiftId = Z.ShiftId WHERE Z.IdUser = A.IdUser),(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,C.RecordTime)))) AND (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift X INNER JOIN UserShift Z ON X.ShiftId = Z.ShiftId WHERE Z.IdUser = A.IdUser),(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(DD,1,CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime)))))) AND M.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN(SELECT H.CuttingHour FROM Shift H INNER JOIN UserShift G ON H.ShiftId = G.ShiftId WHERE G.IdUser = A.IdUser) = 0
           THEN (MIN(CONVERT(TIME,C.RecordTime)))
     END As [Registro Entrada],
     CASE
        WHEN(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift H INNER JOIN UserShift G ON H.ShiftId = G.ShiftId WHERE G.IdUser = A.IdUser) <> 0
            THEN (SELECT MIN(CONVERT(TIME,RecordTime)) FROM Record M WHERE M.RecordTime BETWEEN (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift X INNER JOIN UserShift Z ON X.ShiftId = Z.ShiftId WHERE Z.IdUser = A.IdUser),(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,C.RecordTime)))) AND (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift X INNER JOIN UserShift Z ON X.ShiftId = Z.ShiftId WHERE Z.IdUser = A.IdUser),(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(DD,1,CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime)))))) AND M.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN(SELECT H.CuttingHour FROM Shift H INNER JOIN UserShift G ON H.ShiftId = G.ShiftId WHERE G.IdUser = A.IdUser) = 0
           THEN (MAX(CONVERT(TIME,C.RecordTime)))
    END As [Registro Salida]
FROM [User] A 
INNER JOIN  Department B ON A.IdDepartment = B.IdDepartment
INNER JOIN Record C ON A.IdUser = C.IdUser
INNER JOIN UserShift E ON A.IdUser = E.IdUser 
INNER JOIN Shift D ON E.ShiftId = D.ShiftId
INNER JOIN ShiftDetail F ON E.ShiftId = F.ShiftId
WHERE A.IdUser = '5516'
GROUP BY B.IdDepartment, B.IdParent, A.IdUser, A.Name, B.Description, CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime,102),
(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))
```

but when I try to execute the query it throws the following error

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Column 'Record.RecordTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

but I'm trying to put it in the query because depending, if you have cut-off time is to say that the cut-off time is not zero, but throws me the error mentioned above, I do not know what the error is

expected result this

[image]

but if I touch the recordtime field it brings me these results and the ones I want are those of the other image

[image]

Comment: The error message says it all! You should GROUP BY all columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions!

Comment: Slight detour....https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: I suspect you are severely over-complicating things. Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish (including sample data and expected output)? You may get a more useful answer.

Comment: I don't understand why somebody would give this question an upvote. It does not have enough information to provide a real answer. It doesn't even have the entire query. OP - I would suggest you take a look here for improving this question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @jarlh that's what I do not want to say that the things that I'm converting in a time or the ones that I'm becoming, that's where I have the doubt

Comment: The problem is in DATEADD: 
(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,C.RecordTime).
But for more help, it would be useful to know what you are trying to accomplish, a sample and the expected output.

Comment: Ask another question (and delete this one).  First, try to simplify the problem a bit.  I'm guessing all those tables are not necessary to reproduce the problem.  Then provide sample data and desired results.  You might actually get answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but edit ask and add expect results

Comment: No one can help you if you give half of a query.  Somewhere in your query, there's a `SELECT Record.RecordTime`, but it's not in `GROUP BY`.  That's all I can tell with half query.

Comment: @Eric I'm going to edit the question with the complete code so you can understand

Comment: @Eric edit the question with the complete query so you can see the code completely and the results that I hope you place an image

Comment: In the `GROUP BY`, what happen if you replace `CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime,102),
(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime)` with just `C.RecordTime`?

Comment: @Eric it brings me duplicate data

Comment: @Frankenstainero No error.  That's a good start.  Now you need to work on the logic to remove duplicate.

Comment: @Eric That's what I'm trying to do, but I'm trying to help

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I'm seeing if someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

The problem are `Registro Entrada` and `Registro Salida`:

```
 CASE
    WHEN(SELECT H.CuttingHour FROM Shift H INNER JOIN UserShift G ON H.ShiftId = G.ShiftId WHERE G.IdUser = A.IdUser) <> 0
        THEN (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(TIME,RecordTime)) FROM Record M WHERE M.RecordTime BETWEEN (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift X INNER JOIN UserShift Z ON X.ShiftId = Z.ShiftId WHERE Z.IdUser = A.IdUser),(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,C.RecordTime)))) AND (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift X INNER JOIN UserShift Z ON X.ShiftId = Z.ShiftId WHERE Z.IdUser = A.IdUser),(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(DD,1,CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime)))))) AND M.IdUser = A.IdUser)
    WHEN(SELECT H.CuttingHour FROM Shift H INNER JOIN UserShift G ON H.ShiftId = G.ShiftId WHERE G.IdUser = A.IdUser) = 0
       THEN (MIN(CONVERT(TIME,C.RecordTime)))
 END As [Registro Entrada],
 CASE
    WHEN(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift H INNER JOIN UserShift G ON H.ShiftId = G.ShiftId WHERE G.IdUser = A.IdUser) <> 0
        THEN (SELECT MIN(CONVERT(TIME,RecordTime)) FROM Record M WHERE M.RecordTime BETWEEN (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift X INNER JOIN UserShift Z ON X.ShiftId = Z.ShiftId WHERE Z.IdUser = A.IdUser),(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,C.RecordTime)))) AND (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift X INNER JOIN UserShift Z ON X.ShiftId = Z.ShiftId WHERE Z.IdUser = A.IdUser),(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(DD,1,CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime)))))) AND M.IdUser = A.IdUser)
    WHEN(SELECT H.CuttingHour FROM Shift H INNER JOIN UserShift G ON H.ShiftId = G.ShiftId WHERE G.IdUser = A.IdUser) = 0
       THEN (MAX(CONVERT(TIME,C.RecordTime)))
END As [Registro Salida]
```

You have to use a GROUP BY because of:

```
(MIN(CONVERT(TIME,C.RecordTime)))
```

and:

```
(MAX(CONVERT(TIME,C.RecordTime)))
```

But you also use `(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,C.RecordTime))))`, and this is not on `GROUP BY`. Has to be, or replace `CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime,102), (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime)` with just `C.RecordTime`.

But this gives you duplicate data. So my solution is put a subquery instead
of `(MIN(CONVERT(TIME,C.RecordTime)))` and `(MAX(CONVERT(TIME,C.RecordTime)))` and use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT distinct
     B.IdDepartment,
     B.IdParent,
     CASE 
        WHEN B.IdParent = 3 THEN 'SANTO DOMINGO'
        WHEN B.IdParent = 4 THEN 'BAVARO'
        ELSE 'INACTIVOS' END AS Localidad, 
     A.IdUser As Codigo, 
     A.Name As Nombre, 
     B.Description As Departamento,
     CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime,102) As Fecha,
     CASE
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 1 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 6 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 2 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 0 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 3 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 1 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 4 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 2 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 5 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 3 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 6 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 4 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN  (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 7
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2InMinute),2) + ':00')
                FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 5 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
            END AS [Hora Entrada],
     CASE
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 1 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 6 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 2 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 0 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 3 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 1 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 4 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 2 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 5 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 3 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 6 
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                  FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 4 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN (SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))) = 7
            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutHour),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,G.T2OutMinute),2) + ':00')
                FROM ShiftDetail G INNER JOIN UserShift H ON G.ShiftId = H.ShiftId WHERE G.DayId = 5 AND H.IdUser = A.IdUser)
            END AS [Hora Salida],
     CASE
        WHEN(SELECT H.CuttingHour FROM Shift H INNER JOIN UserShift G ON H.ShiftId = G.ShiftId WHERE G.IdUser = A.IdUser) <> 0
            THEN (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(TIME,RecordTime)) FROM Record M WHERE M.RecordTime BETWEEN 
            (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift X INNER JOIN UserShift Z ON X.ShiftId = Z.ShiftId WHERE Z.IdUser = A.IdUser),/*(SELECT */CONVERT(DATETIME,C.RecordTime)/*)*/)) AND 
            (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift X INNER JOIN UserShift Z ON X.ShiftId = Z.ShiftId WHERE Z.IdUser = A.IdUser),/*(SELECT */CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(DD,1,CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime))/*)*/))) AND M.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN(SELECT H.CuttingHour FROM Shift H INNER JOIN UserShift G ON H.ShiftId = G.ShiftId WHERE G.IdUser = A.IdUser) = 0
           THEN (select MIN(CONVERT(TIME,M.RecordTime)) from Record M where M.IdUser=A.IdUser and CONVERT(DATE,M.RecordTime,102) = CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime,102) and DATEPART(WEEKDAY,M.RecordTime) = (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime)))
     END As [Registro Entrada],
     CASE
        WHEN(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift H INNER JOIN UserShift G ON H.ShiftId = G.ShiftId WHERE G.IdUser = A.IdUser) <> 0
            THEN (SELECT MIN(CONVERT(TIME,RecordTime)) FROM Record M WHERE M.RecordTime BETWEEN 
            (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift X INNER JOIN UserShift Z ON X.ShiftId = Z.ShiftId WHERE Z.IdUser = A.IdUser),/*(SELECT */CONVERT(DATETIME,C.RecordTime)/*)*/)) AND 
            (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,(SELECT CuttingHour FROM Shift X INNER JOIN UserShift Z ON X.ShiftId = Z.ShiftId WHERE Z.IdUser = A.IdUser),/*(SELECT */CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(DD,1,CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime))/*)*/))) AND M.IdUser = A.IdUser)
        WHEN(SELECT H.CuttingHour FROM Shift H INNER JOIN UserShift G ON H.ShiftId = G.ShiftId WHERE G.IdUser = A.IdUser) = 0
           THEN (select MAX(CONVERT(TIME,M.RecordTime)) from Record M where M.IdUser=A.IdUser and CONVERT(DATE,M.RecordTime,102) = CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime,102) and DATEPART(WEEKDAY,M.RecordTime) = (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime)))
    END As [Registro Salida]
FROM User A 
INNER JOIN Department B ON A.IdDepartment = B.IdDepartment
INNER JOIN Record C ON A.IdUser = C.IdUser
INNER JOIN UserShift E ON A.IdUser = E.IdUser 
INNER JOIN Shift D ON E.ShiftId = D.ShiftId
INNER JOIN ShiftDetail F ON E.ShiftId = F.ShiftId
WHERE A.IdUser = '5516'
--GROUP BY B.IdDepartment, B.IdParent, A.IdUser, A.Name, B.Description,
/*CONVERT(DATE,C.RecordTime,102), (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,C.RecordTime))*/
```